# Using Template For Returned JSON Data From Server

Tags: kendo-ui

I was looking at the Window component documentation. There is a request option called "template". I am assuming this template can be used to format JSON data returned from the server. So, the template I used was the following:

```
"#= html #"
```

The data returned from the server is something like:

```
"html": "<span>Hello world!</span>",
"instanceId": "10A",
"data": null
```

However, I always get a Javascript error that says "ReferenceError: html is not defined".

Any ideas why html is not defined though it comes in the response body?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify that the return data type is json.

Example:

```
$("#win").kendoWindow({
    content: {
        url     : "/getData",
        template: "#= html #",
        dataType: "json"
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, mate. Better response time than Kendo Premium forums.